# It takes so long to left join & create table in MySQL (indexing done)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to left join and create table. It is a very simple left join method and I already created index for the variables. However, it takes so long to execute the process. What have I done wrong...?

My code is as such:

```
create table rep_test.can_em
select 
a.ACD_ID,
b.RIN
from rep_time.connections as a
left join rep_time.employee_connections as b
on a.CONNECTION_IDENTIFIER = b.CONNECTION_IDENTIFIER
```

I created index on such variables

```
ACD_ID, RIN and CONNECTION_IDENTIFIER.
```

Also, dataType for each variable is :

```
ACD_ID : bigint(20)
RIN: bigint(20)
CONNECTION_IDENTIFIER: VARCHAR(255)
```

Any help will be appreciated. I stopped the process after 2 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query:

```
create table rep_test.can_em
    select c.ACD_ID, ec.RIN
    from rep_time.connections c left join
         rep_time.employee_connections ec
         on c.CONNECTION_IDENTIFIER = ec.CONNECTION_IDENTIFIER;
```

The optimal index is on `employee_connections(CONNECTION_IDENTIFIER, RIN)`.

Because of the `left join`, all the data in the first table is returned.  Perhaps the volume of the data is causing the performance problem.

Comment: Hi I tried, but it still took me a long time, so I had to stop. I also made another index on `connections(CONNECTION_IDENTIFIER, ACD_ID)` and tried to run the code above. Seems like neither of these wouldn't solve the problem..